# how to connect ros with usarsim ( beginner)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

iam new user for usarsim and ros and i want some help to know how ican connect to gether

i installed ros in ubuntu14.04 and i start reading turtuoials
and usarsim in windows

but i dont know the plan and and how ican do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198591/how-to-connect-ros-with-usarsim-(-beginner)/) by [ksmksam](https://answers.ros.org/users/20913/ksmksam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-11-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-01**:
Related questions with good discussions: http://answers.ros.org/question/76855/usarsim-and-ros-integration/ and http://answers.ros.org/question/193669/usarsim_inf-not-working-with-teleop_twist_keyboard/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi @ksmksam, for connecting ROS with Usarsim you need a usarsim_inf package which acts as an interface between ROS and USARsim you can download it from [Git Repository](https://github.com/hrnr/ros-usarsim), this repository has a stack named **ros-usarsim which has many package along with usarsim_inf**, download it and make it via rosmake command, then use it to connect with usarsim, to see the step by step procedure how to connect ROS with Usarsim using usarsim_inf [Check our blog](http://tucrlab.wordpress.com/usarsim-and-ros/).

Hope this will work.

---

Originally posted by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) with karma: 351 on 2014-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1